# Eliminate unused class definitions from generated java objects when using eclipse and JAXB

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xsd, jaxb

I have an xsd that is importing other xsd files and those xsd files also import other xsd files. I'm generating java class objects for only part of the xsd files being imported using a jaxb external file inside the Eclipse IDE wizard, I'm getting A LOT of extra packages that I do not need.  Is there a way in the jaxb external file to eliminate the extra xsd files instead of manually deleting them?

My xsd looks like:

```
   <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            This extension schema defines the elements and types needed for the Template IEPD.
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>

    <xs:import schemaLocation="../niem/niem-core/3.0/niem-core.xsd" namespace="http://release.niem.gov/niem/niem-core/3.0/"/>
    <xs:import schemaLocation="../niem/structures/3.0/structures.xsd" namespace="http://release.niem.gov/niem/structures/3.0/"/>

    <xs:element name="TemplateExchange" type="template:TemplateExchangeType">
        <xs:annotation><xs:documentation>
            A timestamped exchange.
        </xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="TemplateExchangeType">
        <xs:annotation><xs:documentation>
            A data type for a timestamped exchange.
        </xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="structures:ObjectType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="nc:DateTime"/>
                    <xs:element ref="nc:VehicleUseText" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

And my current jcb file looks like:

```
<jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="10000" 
    generateElementClass="true" 
    optionalProperty="isSet">
</jaxb:globalBindings>

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd/sample-exchange/TemplateExchange.xsd">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <!-- For each definition, append the type to the end of the name -->
        <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jaxb:elementName suffix="Element"/>
            <jaxb:typeName suffix="Type"/>
            <jaxb:modelGroupName suffix="Group"/>
        </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

I'm looking for an easy method to eliminate all the unnecessary classes that are generated. When using the wizard, I am getting about 1700 classes! Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, my question has to with the all the imports another xsd is pulling into the base xsd.  I can create separate packages for each xsd being pulled in.  But I want to eliminate all the extra packages created by using the jcb file.